# Regex in textreplace google app script is not working

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Trying to replace text + date just by date using regex, but it not works:

```
function myfunction() {  
   var SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("");
   var Files = SourceFolder.getFiles()
   var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
   while(Files.hasNext()) {
       var file = Files.next();
       body.replaceText("Date: \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}", "31.10.2020")
   }  
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Backslashes must be doubled and the `.` should be escaped: `.replaceText("Date: \\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}", "31.10.2020")`

Comment: Thank Wiktor so much double backslashes arre working. But script doesn't want to change it in all files in the folder - Files.hasNext() is not working, maybe some one have any ideas about it

Comment: Probably problem is with this line var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody(); but I didnt find anything else in api

Comment: Solve: 
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
       var body = doc.getBody();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();` is declared outside of the loop, so you always refer to the active document body in your `while` loop.

You may use

```js
while(Files.hasNext()) {
   var file = Files.next();
   var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId()); 
   var body = doc.getBody();
   body.replaceText("Date: \\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}", "31.10.2020")
}
```

The point here is to use double backslashes in the pattern, and escape the dot chars since otherwise a `.` matches any char but a line break char.

Comment: Thank U Wiktor so much for your help. I have problem with backspace now))) Between 'Date:' and  first '\\'

Comment: If you have another issue, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

function replace_text() {

```
   // Get speadshhet with ID
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   
   // Returns cell with ID (User will insert his or her folder ID in cell B3)
   var range = sheet.getRange(3, 2);
   var values = range.getDisplayValue(); 
   
   // Get folder by ID - insert your folder ID
   var SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(values); 
   
   // Iterate throw all files in folder
   var Files = SourceFolder.getFiles();
   while(Files.hasNext()) {
       var file = Files.next();
     
   //  Get all documents ID  
       var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
       
   //  Get text body to replace  
       var body = doc.getBody();

   //  Insert header in document + alignment  
       var header = body.insertParagraph(0, 'TEXT');
       header.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT)
       
   // Text style    
       var style = {};
       //style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
       style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Arial';
       style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 9;
       style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#000000';
       body.setAttributes(style)
       Logger.log(body)
       
    // Replacing text   
       body.replaceText("Text", " ");
       body.replaceText("Date:\\s*\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}", "31.10.2020")
       
       var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
       for (var i = 7; i < paragraphs.length; i++) { 
          var paragraph = paragraphs[i];
          paragraph.setAlignment(DocumentApp.Horizontal`enter code here`Alignment.LEFT)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code I've got in the end of my project. Maybe it'll be usefull for someone